# Special grammar in scala

Tags: scala

I am very new at Scala and Spark area, and I found a strange grammar usage in the scala inside the Apache beam project and I can't understand.

Here is the strange place:

```
JavaDStream<Metadata> metadataDStream = mapWithStateDStream.map(new Tuple2MetadataFunction());
// register ReadReportDStream to report information related to this read.
new ReadReportDStream(metadataDStream.dstream(), id, getSourceName(source, id), stepName)
    .register();
```

From the above code, you can see inside the constructor of ReadReportDstream, the first parameter is

```
metadataDStream.dstream()
```

If we go inside the dstream() method, you will see the following code:

```
class JavaDStream[T](val dstream: DStream[T])(implicit val classTag: ClassTag[T])
extends AbstractJavaDStreamLike[T, JavaDStream[T], JavaRDD[T]] {
```

I am wondering why it uses "metadataDStream.dstream()" in the constructor instead of "metadataDStream.dstream"? What does the "()" do?

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly a question of convention. Methods with empty parameter lists are evaluated for their side-effects. Methods without parameters are assumed to be purely functional, and free of side-effects. You can read more about that here - https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html (Arity-0 section)

So in that case, we're probably having some side-effects in `metadataDStream.dstream()`. However, syntactically writing it as `metadataDStream.dstream` won't be an error.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but there is no method called dstream, it is a variable

Comment: I didn't dig into sources, but seems like it actually has such method - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/streaming/api/java/JavaDStream.html